# IntelliJ IDEA hint parameters of method

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm just swapping from eclipse to IntelliJ, and I can't find this particular feature.

In Eclipse, when the cursor is inside the brackets of a method-call and I press Ctrl+Space, it tells me which parameters this method takes. Is there something similiar in IDEA?

Answer (score 137):

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> for Mac), it should show something similar.
You may also find the [reference card (PDF)](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard.pdf) handy.

Comment: The action name is `Parameter info (within method call arguments)` (this is useful for searching it in Preferences > keymap).

Comment: @Arvidaa You can search in keymap by keystroke as well (magnifying glass with 3 blocks icon).

Answer (score 32):

Except <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> (or <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> for Mac)

There is new feature in IntelliJ IDEA EAP:

**Parameter name hints**

> Settings > Editor > General > Appearance

preview: [image]

Video from JetBrains about this feature: https://youtu.be/ZfYOddEmaRw

Related question - [IntelliJ shows method parameter hints on usage - How to disable it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40866202/intellij-shows-method-parameter-hints-on-usage-how-to-disable-it)

I'm using:

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3 EAP
Build #IU-163.5219.11, built on September 27, 2016
```

Comment: I was looking how to customize the appearance of the parameter name hints and found this post (bottom of page): https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000004084-Type-hint-colors-customization. Just leaving the link here for reference.

Answer (score 25):

Yes - just press CTRL-P.

Answer (score 10):

Display the parameter-helper automatically, by adjusting the "Autopopup"-timer in IntelliJ / PhpStorm settings.

Navigate to:

```
File -> Settings -> Editor -> General -> Code Completion -> Autopopup in (ms)
```

Set it to whatever you like. Etc. 5 ms.

[image: Autopopup parameter info in IntelliJ]

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl+P if the keybinding is set to "default".