# How to show method parameters hint in Intellij IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide

[image]

> int beginIndex, int endIndex

is important when we invoke methods.

How to show this when the cursor is in the brackets?
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IntelliJ IDEA hint parameters of method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783180/intellij-idea-hint-parameters-of-method)

Answer (score 247, accepted):

Got the final answer.

Just <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>P</kbd> in Windows/Linux

or <kbd>⌘</kbd> +<kbd>P</kbd> in macOS.

[JetBrains reference: Parameter Info](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/viewing-reference-information.html#view-parameter-info)

Comment: Here is reference from jetbrains: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/viewing-reference-information.html#view-parameter-info

Comment: Ctrl+P gives me print dialog in IntelliJ (2021.1)

Comment: @Cromax
you probably changed active shortcuts scheme or shortcut itself. 
`Ctrl` + `p` works in default setting (Win)

Comment: @GreenMarty I admit I may changed some shortcuts, but I can hardly believe I set up a shortcut for printing (for what reason?) — didn't notice it previously, but even 3 other persons gave +1 to my comment, so they had to experience the same, I suppose. Well, I am using GNOME key map, maybe <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> here have this other function?

Comment: @Cromax Most likely you or some plugin changed the shortcut.   Most of modern IDE's comes with competitor's IDE's keymaping plugins.  E.g. i uses IntelliJ mapping in VCS, IntelliJ comes bundled with Eclipse, NetBeans and VS keymaping plugin. I'm sure there are more.  Here is default key-mapping for jetbrains IDEs  https://resources.jetbrains.com/storage/products/intellij-idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard.pdf

Comment: @GreenMarty You seem to be correct — I've just installed IntelliJ from scratch on my new unit and it works as described. No idea what could interfere with this particular shortcut, thou. Thanks for bothering! :-)

Answer (score 26):

To view the method parameters

1. Place the caret anywhere within the call of the desired method or function.
2. Choose View | Parameter Info on the main menu or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>.

To configure the behavior of the view parameter information functionality

1. Open the IDE Settings and click Code Completion below the Editor node.
2. In the Parameter info section, define the following options:

   - To have a complete method or function signature shown rather than a list              of required types, select the Show full signatures check box.
     Make sure to include the required third-party libraries in the project   source path. Otherwise, names of the parameters will not be displayed.
   - To have the list of parameter types for the called method or function shown automatically after a certain delay, select the Auto pop-up (in ms) check box and specify the time period in milliseconds.

Answer (score 18):

If you have non-standard bindings (or want to change what this is bound to), then look here:

`Settings > Keymap > Main menu > View > Tool Windows > Parameter Info`

And see what the binding is and/or change it to what you want.

Answer (score 8):

Default shortcut to show parameter info in IDEA is <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>.

Here is a sheet from JetBrains with this and other useful keyboard shortcuts: https://resources.jetbrains.com/storage/products/intellij-idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard.pdf

Answer (score -3):

This tooltip appears on mouse over events.

Workaround with keyboard:
Try to use quick documentation pop-up CTRL+Q .