# IntelliJ shows method parameter hints on usage - How to disable it

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am new to IntelliJ and recently updated to **IntelliJ-2016.3**.
In the editor for Java code, it shows the method signature upon usage. How do I disable this feature?

Here's an example of a method's signature and its call site:

[image: 1]

**Method call:**

[image: 2]

This behavior was not there in 2016.1.4 version. I am seeing this after update.

Comment: @IslamAbdalla Not always, a simple string.split() should not have "regex: " in front of the parameter, it's obnoxious.

Comment: @Kevin why shouldn't it have "regex:" in front of the parameter? It helps in reminding you that, despite appearances, `string.split(".")` does *not* split on the dots.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou That's more an issue of method naming, not one of showing the name of a parameter or not.

Comment: I have to say, this feature is super annoying. Like the slow animation in which the things appear, and also the fact that it shifts the rest of the code around so that you visually lose your place... not sure what they were thinking

Comment: Regarding readability: It may help when viewing in this particular tool, but if someone reads your code outside of IntelliJ, they won't see the hints. I believe such readability issues should be resolved in the choice of variable names (and maybe creation of variables names), and just generally better APIs.

**Plus...** it obscures line length, where that is a style issue in some environments.

Comment: idea have ctrl+p hot key, which show same information. This tooltips is garbage.

Comment: showing the parameter name in the calling list is super annoying. I just want it to show what I'm typing in it. It just makes the code more unreadable.

Comment: I agree with @Joe. Positioning your cursor to edit a paramter is a HUGE pain in the neck. Just shut it off.

Would be happier with a pop-up hint on hover.

Comment: When I look at my code, columns can be horrendously over the specified limit and I can't read lines of code without side-scrolling. I can't autoformat to fix this because these hints aren't counted toward that limit.

Comment: All fun and games until code review time, then back to "what exactly does `true` mean here?"

Comment: linked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38734111/how-to-show-method-parameters-hint-in-intellij-idea

Comment: If you know that it called a "hint" then you can type "hint" into the settings filter and you can find this setup entry that may be in different places according to the IDE  version. And you can also learn other possibilities: hints on completion that may be useful even if you don't want to see hints general, and color scheme for hints.

Comment: This feature is confusing particularly to newcomers. I see questions like "Why doesn't this work when I call a method: `myObj.someMethod(name: "arg", age: 23)`" on a regular base. Examples: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64006134/507738) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71865654/507738).

Comment: Oh, and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73066884/507738).

Answer (score 210, accepted):

Right click on the hint, then on `Disable`:

[image]

Comment: The keyboard shortcut for this `Alt + Q` (Context Info)

Comment: @Custodio indeed, I forgot to specify that was on under the default Windows/Linux keymap. [Apparently](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/alt.html?keymap=secondary_mac_os_x_10.5_) on Mac it is `⌃⇧Q ` (Ctrl + Shift + Q)

Comment: God why is this so difficult. There are like 5 different related options that don't seem to do anything if I disable them. This answer is the only one that actually worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 301):

Untick the bottom option `Show parameter name hints`

[image: Show parameter name hints]

Comment: Just to be clear, this isnt the very bottom option in IntelliJ 2019.X... its somewhere near the middle of this pane. :)

Comment: In IntelliJ 2019 it is in not in the `Appearance`, not even in the `General`. It is in `Editor -> Inlay Hints -> Parameter hints`.

Comment: for Intellij IDEA 2022
Editor -> Inlay Hints -> Code vision -> Usages , Uncheck this

Answer (score 55):

I find it helpful to use a shortcut such as `P + shift + command` to toggle parameter type hinting as needed. I don't want it disabled entirely.

1. open preferences
2. click Keymap
3. filter by `parameter`
4. double click on `Toggle parameter name hints`
5. enter key combination ie, `P + shift + command`
6. Apply and Ok
7. Now the key combo will toggle hints for you.

[image]

Comment: This solution was a win for me.  Sometimes the parameter hints are useful, sometimes they're annoying, and an easy toggle was exactly what I wanted.  (The only challenge was finding an unused key combination that I could remember!)

Comment: If you want to toggle all inlay hints than make a key for 'Toggle Inlay Hints Globally' ( I used SHIFT+H )

Answer (score 18):

From the [what's new page](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/whatsnew/#v2016-3-user-interface):

> ### Parameter hints
>
> The editor now shows parameter hints for literals and nulls used as method arguments. These hints make code much more readable.
>
> If you find hints redundant for a certain method, you can tell the IDE not to show hints for this method. **To disable hints completely, uncheck Settings → Editor → General → Appearance → Show parameter name hints.**

(emphasis is mine)

Comment: Isn't there anymore. Now it's in the  **Settings → Editor → Inlay Hints → Java → Show parameter hints for**.

Answer (score 17):

In latest version you can find it under **Settings → Editor → Inlay Hints**

[image]

Answer (score 15):

Others have already answered this, but here is a way of finding it without jumping into menus.

Try hitting `⌘ + Shift + A` on Mac or `CTRL + SHIFT + A` on Linux and type the `Show parameter name hints` into the search bar.

[image: Show parameter appears when searching from the Action/Option name search bar]

Comment: lol, @AfonsoLage I think you have a typo, better off deleting and re-commenting if you can no longer edit

Comment: CTRL + SHIFT + A on Linux, tested here.

Comment: If you keep getting a pop-up from terminal when you try CMD + SHIFT + A: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/360005137400-Cmd-Shift-A-hotkey-opens-Terminal-with-apropos-search-instead-of-the-Find-Action-dialog

Answer (score 10):

As of 2022, it's been renamed to "inlay hints"

You can disable it by pressing `shift` + `shift`, then type `inlay hints` and then disable it.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

1. `⌘ + Shift + A`
2. Type `Inlay Hints`
3. **Make sure that the language of your choice has `Types` set up properly!!!** Here's an example for Kotlin:
   [image: Inlay Hints settings]

Answer (score 3):

As on 2022 (WebStorm 2022.1.2), the option is under the *Editor → Inlay Hints*. Uncheck the parameter names checkbox.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For Intellij IDEA 2022
Editor -> Inlay Hints -> Code vision -> Usages , Uncheck this