# Is it possible to disable hints for unnamed parameters in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, parameters, kotlin, android-studio-3.0, code-hinting

I have a variable of function type.

```
var onLengthChanged: (Int?) -> Unit = {}
```

When I invoke the function, hint appears for parameter `p1`, although it was unnamed. I guess that this is an auto-generated name. It looks like this:

[image]

Is there any way to disable hints for auto-generated parameter names only?

According to this question: [IntelliJ shows method parameter hints on usage - How to disable it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40866202/intellij-shows-method-parameter-hints-on-usage-how-to-disable-it) it is possible to disable hints in `Settings -> Editor -> General -> Appearance` unchecking `Show parameter name hints` option. There is also "Configure..." button, but I wasn't able to find any appropriate option to disable hints in this specific case.

Comment: You can name  it `var onLengthChanged: (input: Int?) -> Unit = {}`.

Comment: There are cases where adding parameter name is a good idea. However, often it becomes unnecessarily verbose. Unfortunately there are a lot of such parameters across my project, so adding them all is not an option. In my opinion there is no sense in showing hint if developer decided not to provide name of the parameter.

Comment: If you really want that feature, you should open a feature request. But it would probably take a long time because type hint appears on IDLE much earlier. It takes time for Android Studio to catch up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that this issue has been fixed already when I posted the question: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-19216#tab=History

Everything works fine now.