# Intellij like inline parameter hints in vs code

Tags: visual-studio-code

[IntelliJ shows method parameter hints on usage - How to disable it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40866202/intellij-shows-method-parameter-hints-on-usage-how-to-disable-it)

I would like to see inline parameter hints in VS Code (for golang) --as described in image of above referred post.  Please suggest if this can be achieved with any extension / otherwise.  I tried "IntelliJ IDEA Keybindings" [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=k--kato.intellij-idea-keybindings) but it dont seem to be supported yet.

Any help is highly appreciated.  Thanks!

```html
Refactoring

Linux, Windows  macOS   Feature Supported
f5  f5  Copy    N/A
f6  f6  Move    N/A
alt+delete  cmd+delete  Safe Delete N/A
shift+f6    shift+f6    Rename  ✅
shift+f6    shift+f6    Rename (File)   ✅
ctrl+f6 cmd+f6  Change Signature    N/A
ctrl+alt+n  cmd+alt+n   Inline  N/A
ctrl+alt+m  cmd+alt+m   Extract Method  ✅
ctrl+alt+v  cmd+alt+v   Extract Variable    ✅
ctrl+alt+f  cmd+alt+f   Extract Field   N/A
ctrl+alt+c  cmd+alt+c   Extract Constant    N/A
ctrl+alt+p  cmd+alt+p   Extract Parameter   N/A
```

Comment: Still not in from what I can tell https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/16221 did you find a solution? Would be great to see

Comment: Same here, I hope find some extension for golang inline parameters :)

Answer (score 1):

[vscode issue 92297](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/92297) might land in VSCode 1.62 (oct. 2021):

> ### Replace underline in Parameter Hints with color
>
> Instead of an underbar below the current parameter, using a color would be a much better choice

Examples:

[image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/35271042/137919282-36331de2-44e1-47bb-865b-f9501fb98c5d.png]

Or (dark theme)

[image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/35271042/137919069-8abb411e-9677-422e-ba6e-64a1f64d3f07.png]

This will be closer to what you see in an IntelliJ IDE like webstorm:

[image: webstorm -- https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/33468089/76261399-2d9c0600-625a-11ea-8b93-1cdfc227d35e.png]

Answer (score 1):

I've found an extension for VS Code which works pretty nicely. It's name is **Inline Parameters for VSCode**, here is a link to [marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=liamhammett.inline-parameters)

Comment: This does not support Golang.

Answer (score 1):

This extension support inline parameter hints for Golang in VSCode:

[Inline Parameters Extended for VSCode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=RobertOstermann.inline-parameters-extended)