# How to turn off type hint in java stream sequences

Tags: java, intellij-idea

When I have code in java that uses streams intellij displays type hints about the result of the stream.

I would like to disable these hints

Example with the following code:

```
Stream.of (1, 2. 3)
    .map (n -> n + 1)
    .map (n -> n % 2 == 0 ? "even number " + n : "odd number " + n)
    .peek (System.out:println)
    .map (s -> Float.parseFloat (s.substring (s.lastIndexOf (" "))))
    ;
```

[image]

I have turned off other tool tips for parameters, but the hints after the streams are still present. They are visually very distracting while providing me with little extra information.

I would also be happy if I knew how to change the color or style of the hints (I have Material Theme UI installed)

Comment: The attached picture beginning `Stream.of (1, 2, 3)` doesnt seem to match the code above beginning with `uris.stream()` ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40866202/intellij-shows-method-parameter-hints-on-usage-how-to-disable-it

Comment: @AnuragSharma It is not a duplicate of that post, I have disabled those hints a long time ago, but the stream hints are still displayed.

ps: I did see that post before I asked the question

Comment: @vikingsteve Yes sorry, i copied the wrong code block from intellij, I changed it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**IntelliJ 2019.2 CE**

1. Navigate to: `Preferences -> Editor -> Inlay Hints -> Java`. Alternatively, press `CMD (⌘)`/`Ctrl` + `Shift` + `A`, search for `Inlay Hints`, open the first result, and select `Java`.
2. Untick `Method Chains` tickbox

[image]

Alternatively, you can increase the count of unique types in streams/method chains from which the type hints will be shown. I.e., if your stream transforms from type `A` to type `B`, and then to type `C`, this would be 3 types. If you set it to 2, hints would be shown for 3 unique types and more.

Comment: I don't have the options that you have, perhaps a version difference (intellij idea community 2018.3 here). But seening that it is called 'inline hints' did search through the settings for that. And I did find a way to change the styling sort of solves my problem.

I would accept your answer if i could verify that it works.

Comment: I upgraded to the latest version and see those options now, they do work, so I accepted your answer. Thanks for the help

Comment: You can also right click on a method chain hint in your code file and there is an option there

Comment: Good point! Didn't notice it. Definitely the quicker way than navigating through settings if one just wants to get rid of hints. Upvoted.

Comment: @vikingsteve I did try that, but I had the older version, maybe now I would see it

Answer (score 1):

An easier way!

Just right click on where it says (in your example) `Stream<Integer>` and untick the option `Show method chain hints`

[image]

Alternatively, hit CTRL+ALT+A and type "show me" - you can see the setting for "Show method chain hints"

[image]