# doing java tutorials, getting error messages

Tags: java, methods, constructor

I am doing a tutorial trying to learn basic java. I'm 99% sure I've followed the tutorial correctly, but I get a bunch of these error messages:

```
C:\Users\krist\IdeaProjects\Hello World\src\Main.java:10:45
java: ')' expected

C:\Users\krist\IdeaProjects\Hello World\src\Main.java:11:28
java: not a statement

C:\Users\krist\IdeaProjects\Hello World\src\Main.java:11:36
java: ';' expected
```

In the tutorial, they don't use this symbols, but the code still works in the tutorial.
Could it be there have been some updates in java which changed things, or could I be missing some software to make this work?

Here is the code for Car.java:

```
import java.awt.*;
public class Car {

    // Data types:
    // int -> 1, 2, 3...
    // double -> decimal 34.5, 32.1
    // String -> "a1a2" or "Hello World"
    // Color -> from awt library
    // Boolean -> true/false

    double averageMilesPerGallon;
    String licencePlate;
    Color paintColor;
    boolean areTaillightsWorking;

    public Car(double inputAverageMPG,
               String inputLicencePlate,
               Color inputPaintColor,
               boolean inputAreTaillightsWorking) {
        this.averageMilesPerGallon = inputAverageMPG;
        this.licencePlate = inputLicencePlate;
        this.paintColor = inputPaintColor;
        this.areTaillightsWorking = inputAreTaillightsWorking;
    }

    public void changePaintColor(Color newPaintColor) {
        this.paintColor = newPaintColor;
    }
}
```

And here is the code for main.java:

```
import java.awt.*;
import static java.awt.Color.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        System.out.println("Markus");

        Car myCar = new Car (inputAverageMPG: 25.5,
        inputLicencePlate: "1BC32E",
        inputColor.BLUE,
        inputAreTaillightsWorking: true);

        Car sallyCar = new Car (inputAverageMPG: 13.9,
                inputLicencePlate: "3D20BN",
                inputColor.BLACK,
                inputAreTaillightsWorking: false);

        System.out.println("My Car's licence plate: " +myCar.licencePlate);
        System.out.println("Sally's Car's licence plate: " +sallyCar.licencePlate);

    }
}
```

I'm sorry if this question is phrased poorly, I still don't know all the technical terms to explain this in a very good way.

Comment: `new Car (inputAverageMPG: 25.5, ...` is not valid java, should just be `new Car (25.5, ...`

Comment: `new Car (inputAverageMPG: 25.5, inputLicencePlate: "1BC32E", inputColor.BLUE,  inputAreTaillightsWorking: true)` - something like that is not a valid Java syntax - what is it even meant to do? What `inputLicencePlate: 25.5` is supposed to do?

Comment: You are using Java class constructor as a sort of JavaScript. you just need to pass parameters through the constructor this way:   Car myCar = new Car(25.5, "1BC32E", BLUE, true);  
No need to pass key-value pairs.

Answer (score 1):

this here is an invalid call to a constructor/method:

```
Car myCar = new Car(inputAverageMPG: 25.5,
inputLicencePlate: "1BC32E",
inputColor.BLUE,
inputAreTaillightsWorking: true);
```

instead do:

```
Car myCar = new Car(25.5, "1BC32E",  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
new Car(inputAverageMPG: 25.5,
    inputLicencePlate: "1BC32E",
    inputColor.BLUE,
    inputAreTaillightsWorking: true);
```

This is not right. Java does not have named parameters like this.

The problem is that you are using IntelliJ IDEA which gives you parameter hints. It would look like something like this:

[image: Screenshot]

If you look closely, you can see that the parameter names are drawn in another font.

Sadly, this feature brings a lot of confusion to newcomers.