# Why is VS Code showing this these labels or parameter names for System.out.println() in java files?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I have the java extension pack installed. This just started happening today. Not sure if this is due to some json settings or something else.

[image: inlay hints in java files]

Comment: This should be the function of Java extension to prompt you the content of variables. If you want to turn off this function, could you provide the installed Java extension?

Answer (score 13):

See [Random things such as "s:", "x:", and name of parameters are showing up inside of my print statements](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/2412#issuecomment-1099792332): java extension issues.

> It's a new feature introduced in 1.5.0, called inlay hint. We use that
> to display the parameter names of those arguments.
>
> If you do not want to have them in your editor, you can set the
> setting `java.inlayHints.parameterNames.enabled` to `none`

Answer (score 6):

To disable this setting Open 'setting.json' file

```
(CTRL + SHIFT + P and type "Open Settings (JSON)" to open setting.json)
```

Add this code in this file

```
  "editor.inlayHints.enabled": "off"
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The newest extension has enabled inlay hints.  They are actually helpful, but if you want to remove them:

Mac: Code -> Preferences -> Settings
Windows: File -> Preferences -> Settings.

**Type "inlay" in the search, and disable inlay hints.

Comment: Editorializing on the questioner's preferences is not helpful. The inlay hints (which override the standard Java syntax) may be helpful to you, but might not be appreciated by an experienced Java programmer who already reads Java fluently and does not want to see the syntax artificially changed.

Answer (score 0):

The Java tooltip is now showing you the variable names from the methods in question. [`System.out`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#out) is a [`PrintStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html). The relevant method signatures are [`PrintStream.print(String s)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#print(java.lang.String)) and [`PrintStream.println(String x)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println(java.lang.String)).

Answer (score 0):

lets say you have a function `setPassword` that takes parameter of the name `newPassword`and`oldPassword`. So, when you call that function, it would hightlight what the parameter is supposed to be. like

setPassword(`newPassword:` "SOME_NEW_PASSWORD",`oldPassword:`"SOME_OLD_PASSWORD")

This is supposed to reduce any confusion as to what value you entered is what. Extremely helpful when working with functions that take multiple parameters.

Comment: Regarding "confusion", the funny thing is that in my experience, many newcomers are confused about this notation, because they seem to think the Java syntax actually supports *named parameters*. [Here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64006207/507738).

Comment: yes that is right. it does not support named variables. But, I think this question is regarding the labelling and why it suddenly popped up. the answer probably is that the java extension installed enabled the ide to hint at where the parameters are going. this would be helpful in debugging if you miss-arrange your parameters while calling your function. like, in this answer's case entering the old password in the location of new password. It would give you a visual cue. in this question's case, the `x` and `s` are the names of parameters for `print` and `println` functions.

Answer (score 0):

None of this worked for me so here is how I fixed it:

When I did settings through CTRL + SHIFT + P and type "Open Settings
(JSON)", an uneditable JSON file would pop up called
defaultSettings.json that had the setting I needed to change.

Here is an image of this file:
[defaultSettings.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGOOW.png)

I had to find settings through the file directory (win + R) %APPDATA%
-> Code -> User -> settings.json

Then I just added "editor.inlayHints.enabled": "off",

Make sure to add a comma at the end of the previous line if there was
not an existing one or else an error will appear.

Here is an image of the `settings.json` file: [settings.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZm0a.png)

Answer (score 0):

It's called inlay hints. You can set that to not show unless needed.

In Command Palette -> Language Specified Settings -> Java -> Search for inlay
-> Enable or Disable.

P.S. It's really helpful in debugging Problems, So you can set it to "offUnlessPressed".