# Disable field name description in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I currently don't how was this enabled, but every time I have a file open in the editor with a function that requires some parameters, it shows their name at the left. E.g., in this picture it's showing `"value:"`. I want to disable this so it doesn't show that anymore.

[image: parameter hints]

Comment: If that is in a java file, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/71880286/836330, disable `java.inlayHints.parameterNames.enabled`.

Comment: It worked. Thank you @Mark. I had to set the value to "none"

Answer (score 5):

You have two ways where you can disable this default option

1. Settings panel - affects all projects that uses vs code:

- Press f1
- Type `Preferences: Open user settings`
- Search for `inlay Hints`
- Finally, disable the inlay Hints option
  [image: inlayhintsoption]

2. If you want to disable this setting just for an specific vs workspace, open your workspace settings.json file and paste this inside:

> "editor.inlayHints.enabled": false

Comment: Thank you for helping with this.  Driving me crazy having all kinds of bling on the screen.

Comment: My pleasure @barrypicker!