# Appearance of tiny code block showing parameter type in java files: VSCode

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I was working in VSCode with java files and I did several things (that might cause this problem to occur):

1. Installing extensions from marketplace for Java and C++
2. Installing C++ compiler (using this guide: https://www.msys2.org/)
3. Pulling files from remote GitHub repository whereby my teammates are working in Eclipse and Intellij

Text editor screenshots when type exist in parameter:

[image: java parameter hints 1]

[image: java parameter hints2]

Text editor screenshots when type doesn't exist in parameter:

[image: java with no parameter hints1]

[image: java with no parameter hints2]

So basically, I don't want this type exists in the parameter, i.e., I want my text editor like those in pic 3, 4 instead of pic 1, 2. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/71880286/836330

You can disable those `hints` with this setting:

`java.inlayHints.parameterNames.enabled` set to `none`