# VScode close highlight text suggestion

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to close highlight text as in the picture.
I have no idea what I need to do to fix it.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/I0bAD.png

Comment: Is it the same as https://stackoverflow.com/a/71880286/836330?

Answer (score 0):

As [this GitHub issue response](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/2412#issuecomment-1099792332) says:

> It's a new feature introduced in 1.5.0, called `inlay hint`. We use that to display the parameter names of those arguments.
> If you do not want to have them in your editor, you can set the setting `java.inlayHints.parameterNames.enabled` to `none`