# Why does Github Copilot label method arguments?

Tags: visual-studio-code, github-copilot

I was using Github Copilot to generate integers to add to an ArrayList, but for some reason it adds `e:` before the argument

[image]

I've been using Copilot for a while, but I've never encountered this. Why does this happen?

Comment: This has nothing to do with copilot, it's just the IDE labelling the arguments with the parameter names; usually provided by the respective language server.

Comment: What language and what IDE is this?

Comment: @Bergi it's Java in Visual Studio Code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is VS Code showing this these labels or parameter names for System.out.println() in java files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71865654/why-is-vs-code-showing-this-these-labels-or-parameter-names-for-system-out-print) Also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68698269/how-do-i-remove-inline-parameter-hints-in-vscode) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68720113/1048572)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That’s just how Visual Studio Code renders subroutine calls by default.

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA does it as well; looks the same too.

Comment: Is there a way to remove this?