# How to solve string integration to my code

Tags: java

I'm currently following a coding course for JAVA and the tutor is adding a string to a variable but it doesn't populate for me.

Here is my code :

```
package com.company;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // write your code here
        myName("");            -------->>     THE PROPLEM IS IN THIS LINE TO ADD THE STRING
        anotherMethod();
    }

    //Method
    public static void  myName(String myName) {

        System.out.println(myName);

    }

    public static void anotherMethod() {

        System.out.println("another method");
    }
}
```

HERE IS WHAT IT SHOULD LOOK LIKE

[image: WHAT IT SHOULD LOOK LIKE]

What to do?

Solution

[Link the full code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/go6T1.png)

Comment: Are you just concerned that the text `myName:` doesn't appear inside `myName( myName: "")`?  Is that what you mean?

Comment: So what exactly is the problem? You may want to read [ask].

Comment: Can you ask your problem more clearly?

Comment: Yes @wyck that's exactly my problem

Comment: Like it's greyed out and mine can't be grey it's like if the program doesn't understrand that I want to put a string

Comment: I've just edited the question with a new link for what the code should look like. If you take a look at the line 8 addNums that line work fine with my public static void addNums

Answer (score 2):

So that isn't real source code text.  It's just an annotation overlaid by the editor.  I also found it to be weird and confusing when I started using Android Studio.  The font is so close to the actual text font that it actually looks integrated into your code and moves your text over and everything, but it **isn't actual text in the file** that you typed.  It's just kind of like a tooltip put there by the editor telling you what the name of the parameter is.

They're called [*inlay hints*](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Inline_Parameter_Name_Hints.html) or specifically, *inline parameter hints*.  And they look like this:

[image: Inline Parameter Hint]

In the above example, you just type `AddCheckbox(true, true, "AutoFill", null)` and the editor will inlay the hint text.

If you don't like them, you can disable them by right clicking on them and choosing **Disable Hints**.

See also: [this related Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40866202/intellij-shows-method-parameter-hints-on-usage-how-to-disable-it).

Comment: Yea as he mentioned it's just the IDE displaying the variable name for the parameter in the signature that it believes you are trying to use. I've seen some IDEs do it for language but haven't seen it with Java yet.