# Attribute instance in value

Tags: java, weka

I was going through a private lecture video where the lecturer was trying to build a histogram classifier. I imitated the code though mine returns an error when I get to:

```java
mean += ins.value(attIndex:0);
```

They mention that `attIndex:0` is the first attribute, so for a single instance you call value it returns the value stored in that attribute for that particular instance.

Even so, when they go on training their data they also give this code:

```java
double[] d = train.instance(index:0).toDoubleArray();
```

Where `train` is the data loaded from the `.arff` file. `index:0` seems to work for them, although for me I get the usual errors from Eclipse asking for a field, or why there's a colon. I'm guessing that this has to do with the function `instance` [image] and for the other code `value` [image].
So `int index` is given inside, and for some reason, the individual I'm watching is capable of including `index:0` into it.

Any idea why it's included? what would be the case if I just left `0` in there, or does this defeat the comment they made: -*"for a single instance you call value it returns the value stored in that attribute for that particular instance."*

Here's an example of the classifier:

```java
package TestLEarning;

import weka.classifiers.AbstractClassifier;
import weka.classifiers.Classifier;
import weka.core.Capabilities;
import weka.core.Instance;
import weka.core.Instances;

public class HistogramClassifier implements Classifier {
    double mean = 0;

    @Override
    public void buildClassifier(Instances data) throws Exception {
        double mean = 0;
        for (Instance ins : data) {
            mean += ins.value(attIndex: 0);
        }
        mean /= data.numInstances();
    }

    @Override
    public double classifyInstance(Instance arg0) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public double[] distributionForInstance(Instance arg0) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Capabilities getCapabilities() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return mean + "";
    }
}
```

Comment: I would guess that the `attIndex:` is just something the IDE the person was using displays as a way to help the programmer. meaning that it isn't part of the source code and just a visual hint that some IDEs have as an option. eG IntelliJ calls this [Parameter name hints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40866202/intellij-shows-method-parameter-hints-on-usage-how-to-disable-it).

Comment: I'd recommend sub-classing `weka.classifiers.AbstractClassifier` instead of implementing the `weka.classifiers.Classifier` interface. Then you don't have to implement the two methods `classifyInstance` and `distributionForInstance`, but only one of them. Less work. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java you can't write `ins.value(attIndex:0)`. In Visual Basic there is some syntax like this, but in Java just write `ins.value(0)`. As somebody mentioned before, it's maybe a hint from the IDE. (I saw this in IntelliJ before.)

Comment: If in doubt, always check out the Javadoc for an API. [weka.core.Instance](https://weka.sourceforge.io/doc.dev/weka/core/Instance.html#value-int-) and [full API](https://weka.sourceforge.io/doc.dev/) (developer version, 3.9.5 at time of commenting).