# "x:" ,"s:" pops up automatically when I use println() in java

Tags: java, println

[image: 1]

I don't understand the reason behind this,I hope someone can explain. If I run the same code on other machine in the same IDE "x:" doesn't pop up. It appears automatically when I use the println function

I am using println function and it automatically generates "x:","s:" at the beginning.

Comment: It's an inlay hint. `x` is the name of the parameter.

Comment: Which IDE are you using? (IntelliJ IDEA, Eclipse, NetBeams, something else)

Comment: As @shmosel says, your IDE is trying to be helpful and inform you of the names of the parameters of the methods that you are calling. In this case the parameter names are neither explanatory nor helpful, though. In case of a method with 5 parameters with good names the feature can be really helpful. It may be that there is a way to turn it off if it distracts you. [Inlay hints](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Inline_Parameter_Name_Hints.html)

Comment: Related: [IntelliJ shows method parameter hints on usage - How to disable it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40866202/intellij-shows-method-parameter-hints-on-usage-how-to-disable-it)

Comment: You might want to actually define your switch cases...because it doesn't make sense that you're just printing out each course and then enter a number for the course number. That course number correlates to nothing. Or...you might just want to define those messages in the `switch(case) : course 1: then show chem course etc`.

Comment: just a hint, It would be better if you could write your code lines instead of an image!!

Comment: @Sobhan That’s generally what we prefer here, by far. In this particular case the question is about an IDE behaviour that is not visible in the naked code, so it would not help us. One may argue that the OP could then post both so that anyone else can also paste the code into their IDE and see if the same behaviour happens there. I don’t think it’s necessary, though.