# Intellij IDEA | Python Django | How to call these hints by using shortcuts

Tags: python, intellij-idea

Intellij IDEA. Python Django. Guys, how to call these hints by using shortcuts?

Here is a picture

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the action you're looking for is called *[Parameter Info](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/viewing-reference-information.html#view-parameter-info)* and often bound to `Ctrl + P`, see e.g [here](https://mkyong.com/intellij/intellij-idea-how-to-show-method-signature/).

See also:

- [IntelliJ IDEA hint parameters of method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783180)
- [How to show method parameters hint in Intellij IDEA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38734111)