# How to show parameter name hints for C++ in CLion?

Tags: c++, clion, jetbrains-ide

I know about Ctrl/Cmd+P to show the popup for parameters, however that's not what I am looking for.
[image: Not this popup]

I am looking for the parameter name hints (which can be found in Preferences > Editor > General > Appearance), but as I can see they are only available for TypeScript (on a C++ IDE???).
[image: Parameter Name Hints Popup]
[image: Only TypeScript]

How can I enable this feature for C++?

P.S. Here is a screenshot from IntelliJ IDEA on Java. (Found on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783180/intellij-idea-hint-parameters-of-method))
[image]

Comment: Type hints are not yet available for C and C++ in CLion.

Comment: Seems like it's still not available as of CLion 2018.3.3 :(

Answer (score 3):

Type hints for C++ were added in 2019.2. Enabled by default, disabled in *Appearance -> Show parameter name hints*.

Comment: Are you using a Macbook? Because for some reason I can't get them to show up in CLion on MacOS even though they show up on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

In 2021.1.1 of CLION on linux, The setting name is `Inlay hints`

[image]